# Output a file ONLY if table is populated

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

So I have a File QC to validate all the required fields are actually present and in the proper format. After the Query runs it places any bad records in a table. What I would like to do is export this table using VBA to a file to send bad to the client to show them any bad records so they can edit them and send them back.

```
Command Click 42()

    DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, "", "QC_Table", "C:\Users\moore\Desktop\EST-" & Format$(Date, "MMM-dd-yy") & ".txt", False
    MsgBox "Exported to C:\Users\moore\Desktop\EST-" & Format$(Date, "MMM-dd-yy") & ".txt"

End Sub
```

I use this to export just fine however I want it to only run if the table has at least 1 record. I know I should use and if statement I am just unsure of how to say if the table is populate.

Thanks for any help in this matter!

Comment: `If DCount("*", "QC_Table") > 0 Then "do your export"`

Answer (score 2):

You need to add in a check first.  This counts the number of records in QC_Table. If than number is greater than zero, do something:

```
Command Click 42()
Dim rst as recordset
set rst=currentdb.openrecordset("Select count(*) from QC_Table")
if rst.fields(0)>0 then
    DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, "", "QC_Table", "C:\Users\moore\Desktop\EST-" & Format$(Date, "MMM-dd-yy") & ".txt", False
    MsgBox "Exported to C:\Users\moore\Desktop\EST-" & Format$(Date, "MMM-dd-yy") & ".txt"
endif

End Sub
```